# Variance of expression

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, probability-theory

I consider a random variable

$$A_t = \frac{X_t + C}{e^{gt}}$$

we know that $X_t \sim N(0,\frac{e^{2gt}}{gt})$

I want to know mean and variance of $A_t$

mean is easy, since

$$ \mathbb{E}(A_t) = \frac{\mathbb{E}(X_t) + \mathbb{E}(C)}{\mathbb{E}(e^{gt})} $$

which yields in

$$ \mathbb{E}(A_t) = Ce^{-gt}$$, since $ \mathbb{E}(X_t) = 0$ and the rest are constants.

For the variance I tried

$$\mathbb{V}(A_t) = \mathbb{E}(A_t^2)-\mathbb{E}(A_t)^2 $$

Now: $\mathbb{E}(A_t)^2 = C^2 e^{-2gt}$

and

$$\mathbb{E}(A_t^2) = \mathbb{E}(\frac{X_t + C}{e^{gt}})^2 = \mathbb{E}(\frac{X_t^2 +2X_tC+C^2}{e^{2gt}})$$

since $\mathbb{E}(X_t) = 0$ this should be

$$\mathbb{E}(A_t^2) = \frac{C^2}{e^{2gt}} \mathbb{E}(X_t^2) = \frac{C^2}{e^{2gt}} \cdot (\frac{e^{2gt}}{gt} +0)$$

and so

$$\mathbb{V}(A_t) = \frac{C^2}{gt} - C^2 e^{-2gt}$$

but this is wrong due to my solution....

Can you tell me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean looks wrong to me (EDIT: after you edit it's correct)

Using linearity of expectation you get

$$\mathbb{E}[A_t]=C\cdot e^{-gt}$$

As its variance is concerned, simply remember that

$$\mathbb{V}[aX+b]=a^2\mathbb{V}[X]$$

You get

$$\mathbb{V}[A_t]=\frac{1}{gt}$$